# ASP.NET Core authorization permission access folder with Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

In my ASP.NET Core project, I have the integration with Identity Server. So, users have to login in Identity Server and then they have access to the application.

The design department gave me some static page in HTML5 to publish but only authenticated people or with a specific role can see those pages.

I thought to use the old `web.config` to protect this folder like

```
<location path="subdir1">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

but it doesn't work also because I want to use Roles instead of users.

Any idea?

### Update

A quick solution is to add some setting in the *Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                         .Build();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();

    const string cacheMaxAge = "604800";
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append(
                "Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cacheMaxAge}");
        },
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                           Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "html")),
        RequestPath = "/infographics"
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The directory `html` is in the project's root. The folder is protected but the rest of the website can't read the `wwwroot` folder and for example my home page looks like that:

[image]

and I can see in the Devtool that all files under `wwwroot` are not accessible

[image]

Comment: In the Startup.cs file, try to add `app.UseStaticFiles()` before `app.UseRouting();`. The static file under wwwroot folder (CSS, JavaScrip, and images) don't require authentication. More detail information, see [Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization).

Comment: I applied the changes mentioned in the document. Now I have the CSS but I can't see the document in the protected folder "page can’t be found". The folder and the files are there. Also, locally doesn't work not only on the server

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement but the ID4 token provider doesn't work that way. As per my understanding, `Authentication` and `Authorization` are two different tasks and IdS4 is responsible for `Authentication` only where it will just validate the credential and provide `Access/Identity` token with additional required `claims`. So if you want to `authorize` request then you should implement your own logic(you can create your own service for that purpose or write your logic inside your API).

For authorization, I would strongly recommend using [policy-based authorization](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-a-deep-dive/) in your .NET core app.

Please take look at [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) docs as well.

Happy Coding!