# Protect Static Files with Authentication on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65215275/asp-net-core-authorization-permission-access-folder-with-identity-server), I asked a generic question how to add permission for static content. Here I want to be more precise.

In my project I added a folder under `wwwroot` to simplify the code, where I save the html files I want to protect. This folder is called *infographics*.

[image]

The properties for each file are:

- Build Action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

[image]

Follow the instruction from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization), I changed the *Startup.cs*

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<IdentityServerConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerConfiguration"));

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".my.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.Name = "my.dashboard";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            IdentityServerConfiguration idsrv = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerConfiguration")
                                                .Get<IdentityServerConfiguration>();
            options.Authority = idsrv.Url;
            options.ClientId = idsrv.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = idsrv.ClientSecret;

            #if DEBUG
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            #else
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            #endif

            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("roles");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            };
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                if (ctx.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/infographics"))
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store");

                    if (!ctx.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        // respond HTTP 401 Unauthorized with empty body.
                        ctx.Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        ctx.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                        ctx.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;

                        // - or, redirect to another page. -
                        // ctx.Context.Response.Redirect("/");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

What I expect is when the user asks for `/infographics` the `OnPrepareResponse` verifies the request and if the user is authenticated sees the page. But, after a lot of code changing, the result is always the same (on my local machine):

> This localhost page can’t be found

I tried to add this code to map the folder `html` in the root of the project as `infographics` but without success.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "html")),
    RequestPath = "/infographics"
});
```

Any ideas?

### Update

This is working with **not** HTML files. I think the problem comes from the HTML file because they are static content for ASP.NET.

I put a breakpoint on the `OnPrepareResponse` and call the page `infographics/index.html`. The page is displayed (red arrow) and then the application stops on the breakpoint (blue arrow).

[image]

Comment: If you place breakpoints in that check for the request path in OnPrepareResponse, is it hit? Are the other files within the wwwroot folder accessible?

Comment: No, the application doesn't arrive in the `OnPrepareResponse` and I can't understand why. I tried with an application in ASP.NET Core MVC and I can reach the `OnPrepareResponse` and the function is working: the issue is all static files in the `wwwroot` are protected and for example the CSS is not applying.

Answer (score 3):

For any one else that ends up here searching for protecting secure static files.

**For .NET Core 5.** Documentation has been updated to include how to handle this

Per the documentation:

> To serve static files based on authorization:
>
> 1. Store them outside of wwwroot.
> 2. Call UseStaticFiles, specifying a path, after calling UseAuthorization.
> 3. Set the fallback authorization policy.

Make sure to add a fallback policy as well:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
```

See: [Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to place that folder outside the wwwroot folder, which will remove the static file access to it.

You can then serve your files from a controller like so:

```cs
public IActionResult GetInfographic(string name)
{
    var infographicPath = resolvePath(name);
    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(infographicPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), mime);
}
```

given this is a controller you can use the `[Authorize]` tag to secure it any way you'd like.