# Do not serve specific files in /wwwroot with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

Sometimes I have non-image/js/css files in `/wwwroot`, for internal purposes. For example, maybe I have a `README.md` in some subdirectory, documenting something about that location; that would be the natural place for it.

But in an ASP.NET Core app, everything in `/wwwroot` is served to the client, including those private files.

Can I prevent them being served?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to configure your csproj file to avoid copying them on publish.

For example:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot/**/*.md">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Another option would be to use post-build events to delete the files

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was expecting. It's just I always forget the msbuild syntax for those sort of things! Works nicely.

Comment: I think this is the correct way: `<Content Update="wwwroot/content/**/*.md" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exclude-files). Maybe you want to edit the above?

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a hack, but if you're serving the files with [UseStaticFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileextensions.usestaticfiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you could use the [OnPrepareResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-staticfileoptions-onprepareresponse) callback to do something like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = r =>
    {
        // criteria for whatever files you want to be private
        if (r.File.Name.EndsWith("md"))
        {
            r.Context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            r.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
            r.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;
        }
    }
});

app.Run();
```

Credit: I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234726/protect-static-files-with-authentication-on-asp-net-core) post for some details, such as resetting ContentLength and the Body stream.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a very handy way to customise the middleware.